# How to obtain a cell in QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I would like to obtain a cell in a QTableWidget.

I have tried with the method "item", but it returns 0, even if my table has 1 row and 1 column and I call the method like this :

```
QTableWidgetItem *it = ui->tableWidget->item(0, 0);
```

Comment: Have you made setItem before: https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#setItem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableWidget wont return items beyond column/rowCount

Set the row and column count:

[void setRowCount(int rows)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#rowCount-prop)
[void setColumnCount(int columns)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop)

```
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(1);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(1);
```

Comment: I have created the QTableWidget with the designer and I have created it with several rows and several columns. In fact, when the text of the cell is not empty, it returns correctly the cell ; but I would like to have it with an empty text, and in this case, it returns 0

Comment: then check the docs for item(): `Returns the item for the given row and column if one has been set; otherwise returns 0.`

Answer (score 1):

When you add text to the cell via designer, it automatically sets the item to the cell. While programmatically you must first create then set the item:

```
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem("text");
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0, 0, item);
```

So first of all you should initialise your table by setting the items (even empty).